# Mixing of geodesic flow and rate of mixing

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-dynamics

I know the following result which is if $X:=G/\Gamma$ where $G$ be a Lie group and $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $G$. Then geodesic floe $F=(g_t)$ is exponentially mixing i.e.,
there exist $\gamma > 0$ and $l \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that for any $\phi, \psi \in C_2^{\infty}(X)$ and for any $t \geq 0$ one has

$|(g_t\phi,\psi)-\int_{X}\psi d\mu \int_{X}\phi d\mu| \leq e^{-\gamma t}\|\phi\|_{l,2}\|\psi\|_{l,2}$
where $\|h\|_{l,p} =\sum_{|\alpha|\leq l}\|D^{\alpha}h\|_{p}$ and $C_2^{\infty}(X) = \{h \in C^{\infty}(X) : \|h\|_{l,2} < \infty \ \  \text{for any}\  l \in \mathbb{Z}+\}$.

My question is if there is any analogue of this mixing and rate of mixing in infinite volume surfaces other than lattices w.r.t the Bowen Margulis Sullivan measure. If yes, any reference will be very useful.

Comment: Do you mean the BMS measure? the PS measure lives on the boundary, not on the homogeneous space itself...

Comment: P.S. In infinite measure, every ergodic transformation is mixing (as $\mu(A\cap T^{-n}B) = o(1)$ for all $A,B$ of finite volume). One needs to consider local mixing, etc...

Comment: Right sorry BMS measure. Ok, so even for local mixing is there any kind of rate of mixing? Also, can you say some reference where infinite volume case has been considered.

Comment: Babillot proved mixing of the geodesic flow for the BMS measure. Oh-Edwards proved exponential mixing for geometrically finite surfaces with high enough critical exponents. I think the general geometrically finite case was only recently announced by Khalil. [In the convex cocompact case, the symbolic techniques work well and the result is know before then].

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity. Does Roblin's memoirs deal with any of these mixing stuff? As it's written in French, hard to decode. That's why asking if you have some ideas.

Comment: Your group $G$ is probably assumed to be semisimple with finite center.

Comment: Roblin's book is a good source, I remember learning about Babillot's argument there. I think it is in chapter 3 or 4, although her argument is qualitative and not quantitative. 
The argument is just a variant of Hopf's with some ingenious observation about non-arithmeticity of the length spectrum. 
Khalil's technique is different (basically extending the approaches of Dolgopyat and Liverani). Khalil's paper should be self-contained...

Comment: Also another question out of context. I tried to use Google Translate for this memoir but it seems not effective to translate the entire thing. Do you know any other source where some translated version of this memoir is available/ or essentially the same content available?

Comment: No, I don't know of any translation of Roblin's book.